# How to use react custom package into an angular directive

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, reactjs, babeljs

**Hi i have an angular v1.x application and a react custom package.**

---

I want to be able to use the react custom package into the angular directive, which eventually will display a react component.

**some code:**

---

1. angular app:

**directive that consumes the `my-package`**

```
import app from '../../main'
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Mypackage from 'my-package';

const reactDirective = app.directive('injectReact', function() {
 return {
  template: '<div id="reactapp" class="react-part"></div>',
  scope: {},
  link: function(scope, el, attrs){
        scope.newItem = (value) => {alert (value)}

        const reactapp = document.getElementById('reactapp')
        scope.$watch('scopeval', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
             ReactDOM.render(
                 <div>
                    <Mypackage />
                 </div>
                , reactapp);
           }
        }, true);
     }
  }
})
```

2. The package is linked into the project, so 'my-package' is inside angular's `node_modules` folder.
3. The application uses `bower & gruntfile.js` to gother all the js files of the application
4. i cant use `import` or `require` into the **directive** file.
5. so i miss some `babel`/`browserify` configuration to make this work.????

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way you can achieve this is by using external package like [react2angular](https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular). This package allows you to create angular.js wrapper components which will render specific react components, allowing you to pass props to them. Linking process is quite simple:

```
angular
  .module('myModule', [])
  .component('myComponent', react2angular(MyComponent, [], ['$http', 'FOO']))
```

If you want to create you own wrapping library checkout how it's made [here](https://github.com/coatue-oss/react2angular/blob/master/index.tsx#L18) (rendering, passing props and watching for changes to them)